# Performance of struct member access

Tags: c, performance, optimization, struct

I have a highly performance critical section of code that needs to access several fields of a struct. Is it faster to assign the struct itself to a variable, or use the pointer to get members of the struct, e.g.

```
struct A* = A_arr + n;
int a = A->t - A->s;
```

vs.

```
struct A = A_arr[n];
int a = A.t - A.s;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you have a high performance critical section of code you must have profiled to get to that point. Why can't you just profile again to test this?

Comment: The answer to this would likely depend on a several specifics - such as how many times you're accessing the structure members and whether or not the compiler could deduce that there's no possible aliasing of the pointer.

Comment: Look into the assembler that your compiler produces. For gcc, e.g, this is the option `-S` instead of `-c`.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally you'd measure this yourself to find out. Theoretically, a good compiler will create the same assembly for both.

The second version is more natural, and so is more readable, so I'd prefer that until it was measured and found to be less optimal.

Answer (score 2):

They're most likely the same. If a compiler generates code that behaves significantly slower for one version, it's a bad compiler.